# How to run ONNX model files on Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, onnx

I have a ONNX model file which contains text classifier. I also have data, my aim is to test the model on a new data. However I couldn't run these codes. First I try the codes below, nothing happens

```
model_name = 'text_model.onnx'
onnx_model = onnx.load(model_name)
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
```

Then I try this

```
ort.InferenceSession(onnx_model, None)
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: Unable to load from type '<class 'onnx.onnx_ml_pb2.ModelProto'>'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is the following code

```py
from onnxruntime import InferenceSession

filename = "./svm_iris.onnx"
def execute_onnx_model_from_file(filename: str) -> None:
    sess = InferenceSession(filename)
    x_test, y_test = json_to_ndarray()
    sess.run(None, {"X": x_test.astype(np.float32)})[0]
```

In the [Documentation](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/api/python/api_summary.html#inferencesession) it is specified that you can hand the filename of the stored ONNX-Model to InferenceSession. Another solution closer to your code would be to Serialize the onnx-model:

```py
from onnxruntime import InferenceSession

filename = "./svm_iris.onnx"
def execute_onnx_model_from_file(filename: str) -> None:
    onnx_model = onnx.load(filename)
    sess = InferenceSession(onnx_model.SerializeToString())
    x_test, y_test = json_to_ndarray()
    sess.run(None, {"X": x_test.astype(np.float32)})[0]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. What is json_to_ndarray()? I guess it is a function you created

Comment: Exactly it just loads data from a file which was stored there in json-format. The function takes the json and transforms it to an numpy.ndarray which can be used by the sess.run() method

Comment: If this solves your problem you should mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Can you give an example of "json_to_ndarray()"?